# Get list of created files by clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Is there any way to get a list of files clang created for my source file? I have a very complex and long command line call for clang (actually from Xcode), and I would like to know which files get created besides temporary object files:

(FYI: I had to shorten the call due to SO)

```
clang++ -x c++
-arch
x86_64
-fmessage-length=0
-fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack
-fmacro-backtrace-limit=0
-std=gnu++14
-stdlib=libc++
-fmodules
-gmodules
-fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
-fmodules-prune-interval=86400
-fmodules-prune-after=345600
-fbuild-session-file=/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session
-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module
-Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module
-Wno-trigraphs
-fpascal-strings
-O0
-DDEBUG=1
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
-fasm-blocks
-fstrict-aliasing
-Wdeprecated-declarations
-Winvalid-offsetof
-mmacosx-version-min=10.14
-g
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
-Wno-sign-conversion
-index-store-path
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Index/DataStore
-iquote
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/afds-generated-files.hmap
-I/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/afds-own-target-headers.hmap
-I/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/afds-all-target-headers.hmap
-iquote
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/afds-project-headers.hmap
-I/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Products/Debug/include
-I/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
-I/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/DerivedSources
-F/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Products/Debug
-MMD
-MT
dependencies
-MF
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d
--serialize-diagnostics
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia
-c
/Users/Daniel/Desktop/afds/afds/main.cpp
-o
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-a7sdf68ads76f8asd7f6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/afds.build/Debug/afds.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
```

Comment: Can you show us the command line call?

Comment: It's actually the command line Xcode invokes. I updated my post

Comment: As far as I know this command will create only one file.